# PHP: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make the registration page with PHP, but I'm new to this language and MySQL. So I've been following a tutorial about it. I followed everything correctly and checked multiple times. But I can't see the problem.
config.php:

```
<<?php

$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "useraccounts";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;db_name=$db_name', $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

registration.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
        if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirm-password']) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            $stmtinsert = $db->prepare($sql);
# line 30 \/ \/ \/ \/
            $result = $stmtinsert->execute([$username, $email, $password]);
            if ($result) {
                echo "yeeeet";
            } else {
                echo "nope";
            }
        }
    } else {

    }
    ?>
```

Error:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\registration.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\registration.php(30): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\registration.php on line 30

Comment: Please check whatever your PDO connection string contains, as in: dump it. There's a huge difference between single and double quotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have not   a proper string for dns   use  double quote for eval var in string (and not single quote)

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;db_name=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you pull php variable in single quotes php treat that as string for eg:

```
$dbName = 'mydb';
echo '$var';
```

above statement will output you *$var* not *mydb*. so you can try like this

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;db_name='. $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

or you can use double quotes like:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;db_name=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Comment: Nope, I don't think that's the source of the error. I just realized the error was from line 30 in registration.php file(Should have posted it in first place, sorry). I've posted the error.

Answer (score -1):

The source of the error is in your PDO `$dsn` string. You have to:

1. Remove the underscore in `db_name=`
2. Change single quotes to double quotes so the `$db_name` is recognized as variable

This should do the trick:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
```